# Unity2D Tilemap Collision Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm working on a game and using the new Tilemap features. They are working fantastic so far. So easy to whip up a level. However I am running into issues when reflecting a laser on the tilemap colliders. As you can see in the GIF below the first few lasers reflect fine, but the sometimes in the small crack where the colliders meet I am getting unwanted behaviour for my laser.

The laser is made up of a small pellet sprite renderer object with a trail renderer for the color behind and a circle collider.

Here is my collision code. Where direction is a class Vector2 variable and rb is theGameObject' s RigidBody2D component stashed in the `Start()` function.

```
if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Terrain")) {
    direction = Vector2.Reflect (direction, collision.contacts[0].normal);
    rb.velocity = direction.normalized*GameManager.instance.bouncySpeed;
}
```

What steps can I take to avoid this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting an ELSE on your IF and putting a log there to see if the condition is returning false (some other layer than Terrain)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the condition returns true since the laser is redirected. But some variable is wrong somewhere.

Try to print `direction`, `collision.contacts[0].normal`, `collision.contacts.Length`, `GameManager.instance.bouncySpeed` and `rb.velocity`.

```
if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Terrain")) {
    direction = Vector2.Reflect (direction, collision.contacts[0].normal);
    rb.velocity = direction.normalized*GameManager.instance.bouncySpeed;

    Debug.Log("////////");
    Debug.Log("direction: " + direction);
    Debug.Log("collision.contacts[0].normal: " + collision.contacts[0].normal);
    Debug.Log("collision.contacts.Length: " + collision.contacts.Length);
    Debug.Log("GameManager.instance.bouncySpeed: " + GameManager.instance.bouncySpeed);
    Debug.Log("rb.velocity: " + rb.velocity);
    Debug.Log("////////");
}
```

Compare these values when working and when bugged. Post them here as well if you don't find what's wrong

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out I could make the colliders all a single collider using the Composite Collider component on the TileMap Game Object. This fixed those collision issues for me. Again thanks for your time.